# How to set systemProperty in Gradle Test Suites plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to run unit tests and smokes tests in parallel in gradle. I was able to achieve it with unit tests by declaring below mentioned two SystemProperties, now unit tests are running in parallel.

```
test { // this is main test block in build.gradle file
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled", true)
    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default", "concurrent")
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
```

I have used jvm test suites plugin to place all smoke tests at one place, I tried applying same systemProperty in suites block for these smoke tests but it was not working. All smoke tests are runnning sequentially only.

This is what I am trying:-

```
testing {
    suites {
        test {
            useJUnitJupiter()
            targets.all {
                testTask.configure {
                    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled", true)
                    systemProperty("junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default", "concurrent")
                }
            }
        }

        smokeTest(JvmTestSuite) {
            dependencies {
                implementation project
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone got some idea. Please suggest !!

Comment: Does the lazy API work? `targets.configureEach { }` instead of `targets.all { }`

Comment: You’ll have to provide the details about how your smoke tests are set up in Gradle and what part of JUnit the are using.

Comment: @FranciscoMateo I tried lazy API it is also not working. all smoke tests still running sequentially.

Comment: @johanneslink I have updated the code snippet above. Please check now.

Comment: @Sukhbir Have a look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html. targets.all seems to be outside the test block. But frankly, I've never used the test suite plugin. It's rather new.

Comment: Got it!! I tried this is working now. Thanks @johanneslink.